# Table of contents doesn't show page numbers for EG/CGF doc

Tags: table-of-contents

An example:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{egpubl}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{one}
\newpage
\section{two}
\newpage
\section{three}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Doc style:

https://www.eg.org/wp/eurographics-publications/guidelines/

https://www.eg.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/egPublStyle-cgf.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `egpubl.cls` file from the linked-to zip archive contains

```
\def\l@section#1#2{\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}
 \@tempdima 1.5em
 \begingroup
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
%% DF
%   \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth \reset@font\rm \leavevmode
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth \reset@font\rmfamily \leavevmode
%%
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip
  #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss \ }\par
 \endgroup}
```

Here `#2` stands for the page number.  This page number is correctly to be found in the `.toc` file after first LaTeX pass as third argument to `\contentsline`.  But the definition above simply ignores this `#2` which is never used in the code.

So this is a deliberate feature of this class.  Else it is some oversight but that sounds unlikely as every user will be confronted with the output without page numbers in the TOC for sections.

---

The sample PDF [here](https://www.eg.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/EGauthorGuidelines-cgf-sub.pdf)  does not make any reference to a TOC.  Perhaps it is not expected to use `\tableofcontents` at all?

---

Here is how to force printing of page numbers:

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@section#1#2{\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}
 \@tempdima 1.5em
 \begingroup
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
%% DF
%   \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth \reset@font\rm \leavevmode
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth \reset@font\rmfamily \leavevmode
%%
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima \hskip -\leftskip
% ORIGINAL WITH NO PAGE NUMBERS
%   #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss \ }\par
% PATCH COPIED OVER FROM article.cls
  #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2\kern -\p@ \kern \p@ }\par
 \endgroup}

\def\@undottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth
 \else
  \vskip \z@ plus .2pt
  {\hangindent #2\relax
   \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
   \parindent #2\relax \@afterindenttrue
   \interlinepenalty\@M \leavevmode
   \@tempdima #3\relax #4\nobreak \hfill \nobreak
%% DF
%    \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hfil\reset@font\rm \ }\par}\fi}
% ORIGINAL WITH NO PAGE NUMBERS
%   \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hfil\reset@font\rmfamily \ }\par}\fi}
% PATCH COPIED FROM article.cls
    \hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hfil \normalfont \normalcolor #5\kern -\p@ \kern \p@ }\par }\fi}
\makeatother
```

You may need to change a bit the above as I copied pasted my modifications from article class, and there are slight differences to the original code, so perhaps keep usage of `\reset@font\rmfamily`.  It may be that original code from which `#2` or `#5` got removed was decades old.

Comment: No, it's not expected. Further more, they say, "Do not use page numbering within the final version of your paper." Nevertheless, for my final version, I added page numbers and a TOC, and I'd like to patch it to show page numbers.

Comment: not expected by whom? It is definitely expected by the class authors who have deliberately provided a copy of `\l@section` command which deliberately discard the page number... If you want to show page numbers you have to include the above code in your preamble within `\makeatletter...\makeatother` and replace at very end `{\hss \ }` by the code from article class which does here `{\hss #2\kern -\p@ \kern \p@ }`.  For subsections, you will have to redefine their `\@undottedtocline` so as to contain something such as `\hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hfil \normalfont \normalcolor #5\kern -\p@ \kern \p@ }`

Comment: ah sorry I misunderstood your "No, it's not expected." You were actually confirming that using  a `\tableofcontents` was not expected... sorry about that!

Comment: Cool. No idea how you did it, I find tex illegible.

Comment: @ZoharLevi and you havn't seen LaTeX3 source yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled your example

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{egpubl}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{one}
\newpage
\section{two}
\newpage
\section{three}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

I fail to see your problem.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 here on the left are presumably the section numbers not the page numbers; with article class (I don't have `egpubl.cls`) the page numbers are shown on same lines but at their ends near right margin not left margin.